# Mllib missing values handling

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm using the corr from mllib with basic interface
like

```
val a:RDD[Double] = sc.makeRDD(Seq(1., 1., 0.))
val b:RDD[Double] = sc.makeRDD(Seq(1., -1., 0.))
val r = Statistics.corr(a, b)
println(r)
```

Is there a possibility to have casewise or pairwise removal of NAN and Infinity values?

By Default Mllib provides NAN as a result of corr in case of infinity or NAN values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no built-in function and you need to filter those values out by your own. One approach is to use java.Double (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) functionality:

```
import java.lang.Double.isNaN
import java.lang.Double.isInfinite

val filtered1 = data1.filter((!isNaN(_))&&(!isInfinite(_)))
val filtered2 = data2.filter((!isNaN(_))&&(!isInfinite(_)))
val r = Statistics.corr(filtered1, filtered2)
println(r)
```